# Where to put twilio debug statement in iOS app code? [[TwilioClient sharedInstance] setLogLevel:TC_LOG_DEBUG]

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, twilio-api

According to https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/twilioclient, we can use this statement to enable more verbose logging, to help debug issues in our app:

`[[TwilioClient sharedInstance] setLogLevel:TC_LOG_DEBUG]`

Problem is, they don't say anything about where to put it in the app code.  Has anyone used this successfully?  Where do you put it in the code?  Our project is written in Objective-C and uses Pods.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: usually in your `appDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the code, most people would put it to the app delegate.

Comment: Thanks all, I did this and it worked!

Comment: Not terribly familiar with Objective-C so this was helpful - hopefully helps those in a similar position!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you GIJOW and Sulthan for the helpful responses!  Posting this as the answer.

You can put it anywhere in the code, or to enable it globally, put it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[TwilioClient sharedInstance] setLogLevel:TC_LOG_DEBUG];
    return YES;
}
```

And of course make sure to include `#import "TwilioClient.h"` in the file you're using it in.